# searching from database and showing the output

Tags: java, sql, oracle, swing, netbeans

I have a `JTable` where I am displaying all the data from my database table, and I have a `JTextField` where I am going to search the string for example the `"FIRSTNAME"` of the contact and then I want to display the output in a message using `JOptionPane`.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
package ContactPackage;

import java.sql.Connection;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet;

public class viewContacts extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection conn = null;
OraclePreparedStatement pst = null;
OracleResultSet rs = null;

public viewContacts() {
    initComponents();
}

private void searchContacts()
{
    conn = JavaConnectDb.ConnecterDb();
    try
    {
        String sql = "select * from CONTACTS where FNAME=?";
        pst = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, searchContact.getText());
        rs = (OracleResultSet) pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sql);

        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found");
        }

    }catch (Exception e) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); }
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    searchContacts();
}
```

Comment: well, one thing is that you must close the connection after retrieving the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if(rs.next()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sql);
```

You are displaying the SQL query text here, not the results from it.
You need to get the results from the returned result set `rs`.

Comment: Thanks was able to solve this problem after your help.