# Sqlserver show results in joptionpane with sql query

Tags: java, sql

Hi I want to bring results from a table using SQL query but I am getting the message `SQLServerResultSet3` as a result.

I take as an example the below code but it isn't working for me, any idea what I did wrong cause I am new to this ty!

[searching from database and showing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715572/searching-from-database-and-showing-the-output)

```
private void searchquantity(){
  //ArrayList <Update_del_insert_products> proList =new ArrayList <Update_del_insert_products> ();
         Connection connection =getConnection();

         String query ="SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Pro_Quantity <=20";
         Statement sts=null;
         ResultSet rsr=null;
         try{
            sts = connection.createStatement();
            rsr = sts.executeQuery(query);
            //Update_del_insert_products  update_del_insert_products ;
              if(rsr.next()) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,rsr);

        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found");
        }

    }catch (Exception e) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); }
}
```

=================================================================

```
private void Check_CapacityActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

         searchquantity();

    }
```

Comment: What exactly " isn't working"?

Comment: i am not getting  for exable the products that are below 20 .... that i want is to show the products

Comment: so that i want is to bring results into joptionpane for exable all the products that are below 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check rows for products that  are below 20 in quantity table

```
private void searchquantity(){

         Connection connection =getConnection();

         String query ="SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Pro_Quantity <=20";
         Statement sts=null;
         ResultSet rsr=null;
         int a=0;
         try{
            sts = connection.createStatement();
            rsr = sts.executeQuery(query);

             while(rsr.next()) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,rsr.getString("Pro_Id"));
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,rsr.getString("Pro_Name"));
              a=1;
             }
              if (a==0){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found");
            a=0;}



    }catch (Exception e) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); }
}
```